# Horizontal navigation background colors stop halfway

Tags: html, css, header, navigation

Even though I  have added width 100%, the navigation background color is stopping when the links have run out. Css3 seems a lot harder to do that the older version cSS2. I dont know what to do next, can anyone help pls without knocking the menu out?

````
          ``` /* header */
.nav {background-color:#3333FF; position: relative; top: 0; left: 3px; color: #fff; width: 100%;}
.nav ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.nav li a {line-height: 40px; height: 40px; font-size: 18px; display: block; background-color:#3333FF; color: #fff; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
.nav li a:hover, .nav .menu-btn:hover {background-color: #0000EE;}
/* menu */
.nav .menu {max-height: 0; display: inline-block; transition: max-height .2s ease-out;}
/* menu icon */
.nav .menu-icon {cursor: pointer; float: right; padding: 28px 20px; position: relative;}
.nav .menu-icon .nav-icon {background: #fff; display: block; height: 2px; position: relative; transition: background .2s ease-out; width: 18px;}
.nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:before, .nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {background: #fff; content: ''; display: block; height: 100%; transition: all .2s ease-out; width: 100%;}
.nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {top: 5px;}
.nav .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {top: -5px;}/* menu btn */
.nav .menu-btn {display: none;}
.nav .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {max-height: 420px;}
.nav .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon {background: transparent;}
.nav .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {transform: rotate(-45deg); top:0;}
.nav .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {transform: rotate(45deg); top:0;}
@media (min-width: 48em) {.nav li {float: left;}
.nav li a {padding: 15px 15px;}
.nav .menu {clear: none; float: left; max-height: none; max-width: 100%;}
.nav .menu-icon {display: none;}
@media screen ony (max-width: 500px;) {
.wide ul li {height: auto; width: 100%;} 
.container ul li {width: 40%;} 
h1 span {display: none;} 
#main, #firstside, #second .container, .block, firstsidewider {width: 100%;}
.gcse-search {width:90%;}}
````

Here is some html

````
      ```

<header id="banner"><div class="nav"><input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" /><label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label><ul class="menu"><li><a href="http://index.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="http://news.html">News</a></li><li><a href="http://contact.html">Contacts</a></li><li><a href="http://policies.html">Policies</a></li>
<li><a href="http://members.html">Members</a></li><li><a href="http://volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
<li><a href="http://links.html">Links</a></li></ul></div>
````

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you added

```css
@media (min-width: 48em) {
    ul {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

This prevented nav from taking full width because it's child was floated.
You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Your can remove float and it will work or you can do this

```css
.nav {
    position: absolute;
}
```

or

```css
.nav {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Read more about floating elements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Also. One tip.. When you are using `@media-query` use `px` for width and height of screen. I find it that it works best this way. Someone please correct me if I am wrong

Hope it helped :)

Happy coding

**UPDATE**

Next time please post CodePen or JSFiddle code. It will be easier for everyone to help you :)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I tried the position: absolute but when I do that the header goes under the navigation. That's why I changed it to position: relative; but yes it removed the background color issue. Now I have to find out why the header is underneath the navigation.

Comment: element that has ```postion: absolute``` is getting attached to nearest postioned ancestor and goes above everything else. If it has no positioned ancestor (like your doesn't) it is getting attacked to body. Here is what I like to do most of the time. On navbar i put ```position: fixed``` and ```top: 0```. This will make it fixed on top. And then push content of page down with ```margin-top: 100px```  (here 100px is height of navbar).. If you need another solution comment here and we will do it :)

Comment: You are welcome. Could you just accept answer if it helped so that it can help to someone else.